# Getting distances of points in 2D space in an array in Fortran using the concept of broadcasting (Python)

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, array-broadcasting

I'm new to Fortran and I already have a hard time understanding the concept of broadcasting of arrays in Python, so it is even more difficult for me to implement it in Fortran

Fortran code:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer,parameter::N=6,t_size=500
    real,dimension(t_size,N,2)::array1
    
    contains

    pure function f(a) result(dr)
    real::dr(N,N,2)
    real,intent(in)::a(N,2)
    real::b(N,N,2)
    real::c(N,N,2)
    b=spread(a,1,N)
    c=spread(a,2,N)
    dr=c-b

    end function f

end program
```

Now N would be the number of points and t_size is just the number of different time steps. I came up with this function which uses *spread* in two different dimensions to create a NxNx2 array.

Now I thought of using a line like for example `r=f(array1(1,:,:)` in order to get an array which holds all differences of spatial coordinates of every 2 points.

I already wrote code that does this in Python (taken from a physics textbook for Python)

```
r = np.empty((t.size, N, 2))
r[0] = r0

def f(r):
    dr=r.reshape(N,1,2)-r
```

where I can write later for example `f(r[i]`. (In this case, I left the line r[0] = r0, because it shows that an initial condition is given - later I plan to do this in Fortran by using the random_number subroutine.)

Now I hope it is clear what my question is. If anyone has a better idea (which I am sure there is) to implement broadcasting in Fortran, please let me know.

Please have a little patience with someone new to Fortran and also programming in general - thanks in advance for your replies.

I already tried it with the random_number subroutine and it worked, but I have no way of checking if the output is true.

Comment: The Fortran way is to write loops. Unlike interpreted python compiled Fortran Loops are good and compiled loops are fast. Learn to love loops.